# How insert checkbox to database mysql - laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Hey anyone can you tell me the mistake??

this checkbox i show it from my table genre

```
<div class="row form-group">
  <div class="col col-md-3"><label class=" form-control-label">Genre Film</label>
    </div>                           
  <div class="col col-md-9">
    @foreach($genre as $gr)
      <div class="form-check">
        <div class="checkbox">
        <label for="checkbox1" class="form-check-label ">
          <input type="checkbox" name="genre[]" value="{{ $gr->nama_genre }}"> {{ $gr->nama_genre }}
        </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    @endforeach
  </div>
```

and then this is the form
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZBpg.png)

controller

```
public function tambah_movlist(Request $request)
{
    
    
    $movielist = new Movielist();
    $movielist->poster = $poster;
    $movielist->judul =$request->judul;
    $movielist->tahun =$request->tahun;
    $movielist->genre[] = ($request->genre);
    $movielist->rating =$request->rating;
    $movielist->biaya_produksi =$request->b_produk;
    $movielist->pendapatan = $request->pendapatan;
    $movielist->sinopsis =$request->sinopsis;
    $movielist->save();

    return redirect('/adminmovielist');
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and paste the code rather than images, thank you.

Comment: remove `array_keys()`, just use  `$request->genre`.

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML, you defined genre value as an array so you can directly get genre value through `$request->genre` and can save it in the database. Actually no need `array_keys()`.

Comment: I did it but the value just one

Answer (score 0):

Please change code:

```
$movielist->genre[] = ($request->genre);
```

to

```
$movielist->genre = $request->genre;
```

And check the data type of column genre in the database is it right